# Detecting video encoding H.264/Avc and H.262/MPEG-2

Tags: c#, h.264, video-encoding

I need to test if a file is encoded in H.264/Avc, H.262/MPEG-2 or another format. I have searched the web for magic byte sequences to determine this.

What I found so far is `00 00 00 nn 66 74 79 70` which supposedly tells me that a file is contained in an MPEG-4 container. Unfortunately this container format says nothing about what encoding the video within the container uses.

Is there a simple way to distinguish H.264/Avc and H.262/MPEG-2 encoding? I would prefer using magic bytes or a "free" licensed library for c#.

Comment: _"Is there a simple way"_ - [no](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp). Try [taglib#](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp).

Comment: Hi from what I can se taglib# is under a GPL type of license. Do you know if there is any libs that is under a less strict license that I could use?

Comment: Checkout http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo it will do exactly what you want

Comment: Are your files elementary streams? Can you share a couple sample files? If you have mp4 files with AVC or mpeg-2 video than you have to do a little container parsing.

Comment: Where can I learn more about container parsing?